# About the outconverter of cx_Oracle component for python doesn't work when the value is None

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have a requirement to get data from the database through cx_oracle convert. and during the fetch data, if the value of the Number field is None, it needs to be converted to -1.

I want to use outconverter attribute of the Variable. but I found if the value is None, the outconverter will be fired.

here is my example code:

```
import cx_Oracle

with cx_Oracle.connect("omrscpif" ,"omrscpif", 'ammiceng') as connect:
    def OutConverter(value):
        if value is None:
            return ''
        return value

    def NumberOutConverter(value):
        if value is None:
            return -1
        return value


    def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
        if defaultType in (cx_Oracle.STRING, cx_Oracle.FIXED_CHAR):
            return cursor.var(str, size, cursor.arraysize, outconverter=OutConverter)

        if defaultType == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NUMBER:
            return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NUMBER, size, cursor.arraysize, outconverter=NumberOutConverter)

    # Finally, we will assign the defination to the outputtypehandler of the connect.
    connect.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler

    with connect.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select fordertypevalue, forderqtyfuturecommitted, fbackorderqty from so_send where ftrnflg = 'N'")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
```

and the result is below:

```
[(None, None, 1.0)]
```

how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `outconverter` value is not called if the value is `None` as described in the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/variable.html#Variable.outconverter). If you want this behavior you can log an [enhancement request](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues).

An [issue](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/640) was logged for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. it's very useful in practice, please enhance it in the new version. @Anthony Tuininga